# How to run nircmd.exe process in C# project, Windows 10?

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I wanted to run a nircmd process in my C# project (Windows Forms Application) so i went like this:

```
Process mute_process = new Process();
mute_process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\(**my path**)\\nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1 ";
mute_process.Start();
```

Unfortunatelly my program throws error:

> "Unhandled exception has occured in your aplication. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error [...] The system cannot find the file specified."

Other processes in my C# program work for me (for example running mp3 file from a specific directory). Also, the nircmd process itself works well in the cmd.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to pass "mutesysvolume 1" as an [Argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx), not as part of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you included command line arguments in the filename property. You can use this approach instead:

```
Process mute_process = Process.Start("C:\\(**my path**)\\nircmd.exe", "mutesysvolume 1");
```

...or if you want to continue using `StartInfo`, you can do this:

```
Process mute_process = new Process();
mute_process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\**my path**)\\nircmd.exe";
mute_process.StartInfo.Arguments = "mutesysvolume 1";
mute_process.Start();
```